# Why is Shelob not interested in the One Ring?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-one-ring

Gollum tries to have Frodo and Sam killed by Shelob, so he could get the One Ring back from Frodo's corpse after Shelob would kill and "drink" him.

And Gollum is no stupid, so I guess he knows that Shelob is not interested in the One Ring (yeah, ok, spider means no hand, no fingers, so no place to "properly" put the ring on, but I can't believe the meaning/effect/power of the One Ring has such a material restriction as being wearable only by a human-like finger).

Why has she no desire to possess the One Ring? Even Gandalf, Galadriel and anybody else in the books seems to be tempted (or at least assumed temptable) by the One Ring, with the main exception being Tom Bombadil.

What makes Shelob different?

In the already existing questions the answers refer to Shelob just wanting to kill and eat everything (but not vegetables), so I can imagine another creature, other than Shelob, that only wants to kill pigs and eat pigs, probably a very insatiable hobbit. Or a troll. Are they also immune to the power of the ring?

The last paragraph is mostly a joke to say that I'm not really satisfied with *Shelob only wants to kill and eat, so she's not interested in the One Ring*.

Comment: The ring grants power over others; Shelob just wants to eat them.

Comment: _The ring grants power over others; Gandalf just wants to help them_, right, @DavidW?

Comment: Isn't the One Ring trying to get back to Sauron at that point? It's probably a lot more difficult to convince an ancient giant spider to go on a cross-country road trip to Mordor, even if she could be invisible when doing so.

Comment: @Enrico The peril for Gandalf is that he _could_ make use of the ring's power to help others; unfortunately using the ring's power would corrupt him.

Comment: @DavidW, corrupt him? As in changing his will of helping into a will of dominating? It could still change Shelob's will of eating into will of dominating.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The other question is cut and dry: did she know? The answer is also cut and dry: "little did she know..."  This question on the other hand, is clearly an attempt to delve into the character and motivation of Shelob.

Comment: @elemtilas The question isn't the same as the duplicate, but the answer there clearly answers this question.  She does not care, she only wants to kill everything and eat it.

Comment: Do you see a finger she could put the ring on....?

Comment: @DavidW -- Well, yeah, that's the point of this question. *Why* doesn't she care? What makes her different?

Comment: @Moo if you had read my question you would know why your comment is unneeded.

Comment: The Ring to an extent has a mind of its own.  Would it even want to try to corrupt something that would have a difficult time carrying the Ring to Sauron, even if it wanted to?  There is also tradition of Dark Lords finding it hard to control giant spiders (Morgoth and Ungoliant).

Comment: @suchiuomizu, your comment makes a lot of sense.